# LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -128

Tags: macos, unix, sublime-text-2

I' opening an ML file from the terminal using an `open` command is OS X. Currently, the bindings are such that it opened the file through Sublime Text 2.

I get the following error whenever I first open the file somefile.ml:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -128 for the file /Users/.../somefile.ml
```

I deleted the LaunchServices.plist file as I remember adding support for opening files with no extensions — but still the problem persists.

I don't understand what the error conforms to or why is it showing up after all of these changes. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the Launch Services database?

Comment: I did rebuild the database. I've tried restarting and it still occurs.